# Is it the dharma of Rakshasas to be evil?

Tags: dharma, rakshasa

I remember Ravana being berated for being adharmic (fighting while rendering himself invisible, if i recall right)  and he says thats the way Rakshasas behave.

Is Rakshasa Dharma described anywhere?

Comment: I've wondered about this before, and I don't think so. They are naturally evil due to lots of Tamas and Rajas guna, but I think it's still a sin for them to kill people, rape, etc.